# How do I stretch an image according to text content?

Tags: css

I am trying to do a chat conversation bubble using CSS.
The bubble is an image, and the text is dynamically changed based on the user
input. I am trying to fit the image to the text, meaning that if the user inputs a word the image would be at the word size, and if he inputs a sentence it will be at the sentence length.

How do I stretch the image according to text content?

```html
<div className="msg_container">                
    <img  className="conversation_image" src={require(`./../assets/images/speech_bubble.png`)} alt="Conversation"/>
    <div dir="rtl"  className="user_message_text">
        { message.messageText }                   
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe is better have the image as background and background-size contain

Answer (score -1):

This  might be what you are looking for :

```js
var p = document.getElementById('text')

document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('input', function() {
  p.innerHTML = event.target.value;
})
```

```css
p {
  background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
  width: min-content;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="text">random text</p>
</div>

<input id="input" placeholder="add text">
```